# Property for picker data won't retain result of for loop

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, var

I'm new to Swift and am implementing my first UIPickerView. It works fine if I set the pickerData directly in `viewDidLoad` like `pickerData = ["item1", "item2"]`. But I need to construct the picker items from a Firebase database.

I am able to construct the picker items just fine using a method that pulls the data from the database and creates a list. Then I take that list and construct my picker items. I can print the array and I see that the array is constructed properly.

But when the array is done, it apparently either reverts to empty again and my pickerview is empty, or my pickerview got set up before the array was completed and so it is empty.

I tried using `Dispatch.main.async` in several places - including the completion statement in my data retrieval function, around the building of the `pickerData`, etc. I also tried putting the entire code for the data retrieval and the construction of the `pickerData` array into `viewDidLoad`, but it's always the same. `pickerData` does not keep the array I constructed for it, and the pickerView is empty.

Here's my code (written in Xcode 10, Swift 4.2), from `viewDidLoad`:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    // Set up the pickerview
    ToyService.getToyList(kid: self.kid!) { (toyList) in
        self.pickerData.removeAll()

        // Go through each toy item and create a picker item from it

        for item in toyList {
            // Set up a formatter to work with the price as a string
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

            let price = formatter.string(from: item.price!)
            let pickerItem:String = item.title! + " " + "($" + price! + ")"

            self.pickerData.append(pickerItem)

            print(self.pickerData)
        }

        print("here's the pickerdata: \(self.pickerData)")
    }

    print("here's the pickerdata again: \(self.pickerData)")
} // end of viewDidLoad
```

The output of the print statements is as follows (notice the last print statement prints first, and it prints an empty array!):

> here's the pickerdata again: []
>
> ["doll ($0.75)"]
>
> ["doll ($0.75)", "bear ($0.75)"]
>
> ["doll ($0.75)", "bear ($0.75)", "truck ($0.75)"]
>
> ["doll ($0.75)", "bear ($0.75)", "truck ($0.75)", "blocks ($0.75)"]
>
> here's the pickerdata: ["doll ($0.75)", "bear ($0.75)", "truck ($0.75)", "blocks ($0.75)"]

Comment: The closure is called asynchronous so the last print gets called before the closure has executed? What is ToyService?

Comment: ToyService is a method in a separate class to pull the data from the firebase database.  @Sh_Khan gave the right answer.  It was so simple and yet I couldn't find it after two days.  Thanks to you both.  This was my first question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload the pickerView inside the completion as it's asynchronous

```
for item in toyList {   
  // ......
  self.pickerData.append(pickerItem)
  print(self.pickerData)
}
self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

Comment: That was it.  I should have known there was a reload for pickerview like there is for tableview.  Thanks!